# How to group different devices in Apache IoTDB in different data groups and sor the data in ascending order?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have multiple devices in Apache IoTDB, naming like `root.maas.CPEC01.CY-PL1.P9AE-C2G1C01-00ACEQPTSTUS.2` or `root.maas.OR01.LFPEC.M2AE-R3G2C01-00ACEOPTSTUS.2`. How can I group different device into different groups and sort the time series in ascending order by time in Apache IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SELECT EquipmentStatusID FROM root.maas.**.**.**.ACEQPTSTUS.** order by device, time asc ALIGN BY DEVICE` in Apache IoTDB. Just remember to use `device` as the first sort key.